# How to render a template with Twig to string in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, twig

I have an template in Twig(https://www.npmjs.com/package/twig) and I want to get it render to string. I'm using TS.

```
function getHtml(title: string, message: string): Promise<string> {
  const html = await promisify(renderFile)('./template.twig', {
    filename: 'template.twig',
    settings: {
       title,
       message,
    },
  });
  return html;
}
```

But the promise is always pending, even if I use the callback version I can't have the HTML.

```
import Twig from 'twig';
Twig.renderFile('./path/to/someFile.twig', {foo:'bar'}, (err, html) => {
  html; // compiled string
});
```

And with this call the TS alert that doesn't exist default export...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you also reveal your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: yep: 
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*", "./src/**/*.json"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

Comment: You have to be careful with the `path/to/twig` if you invoke your script at `./dist` like `node dist/index.js`, so the path should be related to `dist` instead.

Comment: I run directly in ts with ts-node

Comment: I’m not sure if it will copy your script to the dist too. Just double check by logging out __dirname at the beginning of the function

Comment: I resolve the path of my template is wrong LOL, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this package has incorrect types

Try to use @ts-ignore and pass arguments like this:

```
// @ts-ignore
promisify(renderFile)('./template.twig', {message: 'Hello'})
    .then(html => console.log(html)); // Message: Hello
```

Comment: Nothing happens :( the error doesn't exist more but nothing happens

Comment: Make sure your project has
    "@types/node": "^14.0.27",
    "@types/twig": "^1.12.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "twig": "^1.15.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"

Comment: And try to run it via npx ts-node ./main.ts

Comment: If I run in the root directory ts-node index.ts with your code all works, if the index.ts is inside another folder nothing happens =O

Comment: I resolve the path of my template is wrong LOL, thanks for your help!